# Running python code with openflow simulator

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, simulator

I am using mininet as openflow network simulator. In my experiment I want to bring down a link between two switches in the codes and bring it up later in the mininet console.

Here is what I did:

```
net.addLink( s2, s3 )
net.configLinkStatus( s2, s3, 'down' )
net.start()
```

But after I runing the python code, the link is still up. I do not how to correctly disable the link. Any one can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I figured it out:

```
net.addLink( s2, s3 )
net.start()
net.configLinkStatus( 's2', 's3', 'down' )
```

`net.configLinkStatus( 's2', 's3', 'down' )` should be put after `net.start()`.

Also I should pass `'s2'` `'s3'` instead of `s2` `s3` to `net.configLinkStatus()`.